# How to find change of direction in 3d space

Tags: math, vector, coordinates, physics, robotics

I am working in a project that takes data from moving sensor. we have converted sensor data in 3d coordinates. one of the sensor is planted on hand of the object.
PROBLEM: When object moves his hand in backward direction and then play in forward direction. So i am looking for the frame number at which object hand ends moving back.

Just to clear the problem, this kind of points can come in 3D Here sample image data:

[image: img]

initially i implemented this, using change in y axis. With having some threshold value it's result is good. But only when  object hand moves back and comes forward with decreasing value of y axis. But in ideal case(image) hand can come forward in any way ie with increasing value of y or decreasing value of y. But i am sure that while hand moving in back direction it will always be y increasing (except some noise frame or outlier). using this i implemented this. `

```cpp
std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, bool> calculateBacklift(std::vector<glm::vec3> points)
{
    std::pair<std::pair<int, int>, bool> backlift;
    backlift.second = false;
    std::vector<glm::vec3> distanceVec;
    for (int i = 0; i < points.size() - 1; ++i)
    {

        // vector 
        glm::vec3 distance;
        distance.x = points[i + 1].x - points[i].x;
        distance.y = points[i + 1].y - points[i].y;
        distance.z = points[i + 1].z - points[i].z;
        distanceVec.push_back(distance);
    }
    writeTodisk("distanceVector.csv", distanceVec);
    for (int i = 0; i < distanceVec.size(); ++i)
    {

        // y is major axis and if any of x or z hand changed then i am assuming there can be direction change. this comes from experiment.
        if (distanceVec[i].y <= -0.09 && (distanceVec[i].x <= -0.1 || distanceVec[i].z >= 0.9))
        {
            backlift.first = std::make_pair(1, i + 1);
            backlift.second = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    return backlift;
}`
```

But it doesn't work when hand comes forward in up direction. because change of y axis is positive.

Then i think of find change of direction using dot product. And cos value. But it also detect direction change on axis(X,Z). Or in simple way i can say i want to find corner point in moving sensor data in y axis(major) direction.  Can any one help me to resolve this issue.

Thanks.

Comment: Your question is unintelligible. You say that *back* is +Y, and *forward* can also be +Y, and you want to detect when one changes to the other.

Comment: You need some heuristic to determine when the change in direction (or curvature) is significant. RANSAC is an example of such an algorithm - it calculates the (near-) optimal line fitting for a set of data points

Comment: Do you want to find the "corner point" as soon as it occurs, or will you always have the entire point set?

Comment: @Beta suppose you are moving your hand in back direction ie hand is going up as well. After some point you start moving your hand forward but you hand is still going up. In that case y value of y will still be increment. A good example can be a cricket batsman playing on bouncer ball.

Comment: @chtz yes, i will always have set of points.

Comment: see [Median, best fit of line from mesh skeleton](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45780925/2521214) it thresholds point distance to sliding average. Simple and usually precise enough for tasks like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the entiry point trajectory, I'd just look for the point which has the largest distance to the line connecting the start to the end point. I don't know the vector library you are using, but using the [Eigen-library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/) this would be something like this:

```cpp
std::vector<Eigen::Vector3f> points; // input set of points

typedef Eigen::ParametrizedLine<float, 3> Line3;
// Calculate line through first and last point of points:
Line3 start_to_end = Line3::Through(points[0], points.back());
float max_dist_squared=0.0f;
size_t max_idx=0;
for(size_t i=0; i<points.size(); ++i) {
    // calculate squared (perpendicular) distance from points[i] to the line
    float dist2 = start_to_end.squaredDistance(points[i]);
    // check if distance is bigger than previous maximum:
    if(dist2 > max_dist_squared) { max_dist_squared = dist2; max_idx = i; }
}
```

You should be able to implement something equivalent with the library of your choice.

If you need to handle outliers or noise, use some kind of moving median or moving average instead of single points.

Comment: I understood you concept and hope it will work fine for me. I am using glm mathematics library (openGL). I tried integrate Eigen Library and tried to compile you code. I never used Eigen and getting error in Eigen namespace."namespace Eigen  has no member Vector3f". Also no vector3f is found in Eigen namespace.  

Is Vector3f exists in Eigen Namespace? or i have integrated it wrongly.  I am using MS2017.

Comment: If you want to use Eigen, read the http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/GettingStarted.html Otherwise, just consider this as pseudo code.

Comment: i executed the code. But not getting expected result. just wanted to know will squaredDistance() give perpendicular distance to line created by two end points?  

or do we have nay other method to get solve this issue.

Comment: i don't know why it is working on some set of data but not for some other set of data. Can plz clearefy above algo in your own way. So that i can thing of to do something else. Means what method is doing what exactly. May be i have assumed something wrong.

Comment: I added some comments to the source. I can't tell why it is not working on some data sets (nor do I know, what exactly you mean by "not working"). You may try the method proposed by Spektre in the comments.