# How to detect in real time a "knee/elbow" (maximal curvature) in a curve

Tags: algorithm, curve, polynomials

In the following curve (blue line) I'm trying to detect the "knee/elbow" which should be located around x = 2.5

[image]

This is the set of values I'm using:

> x = {-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2 , -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}
>
> y = {0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100, 107, 122, 145, 176, 215, 262, 317, 380, 451, 530, 617}

I have tried the [Kneedle algorithm](https://www1.icsi.berkeley.edu/%7Ebarath/papers/kneedle-simplex11.pdf) and the [formal definition of the curvature of a graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curvature#Curvature_of_a_graph) (signed curvature). The problem I have with the Kneedle algorithm is that in the real time application (embedded system) I don't know which will be the maximal value of the y axis, so I can't properly normalize the points nor find a slope value which works for all the cases. When using the formal definition of the curvature of a graph I try to fit the curve with an order 5 polynomial (green line) and then get the values of the derivatives to calculate the curvature. Nevertheless, this method finds the curvature around x = -2 as there is a curvature around that point because of the polynomial.

[image]

Could somebody suggest me a way to detect the knee/elbow?

Comment: You know how to numerically calculate first derivative right? (slope), Second derivative is of course just the first derivative of THAT. (rate of change of slope). If you try to curve fit your full data set that will actually 'remove' information from what you need rather than add. Another approach is "bisection of interval" where you keep dividing it in half, and looking for the 'segments' that have the largest "inconsistencies in slope" that you get from sampling like 10 samples in each range and taking the slope of each sample.

Comment: BTW, when i say 'take first derivative' i don't mean you end up with a single number but a new CURVE (set of points). In case that wasn't clear.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Median, best fit of line from mesh skeleton](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45776434/median-best-fit-of-line-from-mesh-skeleton)

Comment: question: what does your data actually model? Because, as is, there is no reason to assume that the function is strictly increasing, it makes far more sense to expect the function to go back down, and so have (potentially) any arbitrary number of identical-valued maximum curvature "points". Also not unimportantly: is your signal smooth, or are we just guessing that this is a smooth function?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans my data actually is the input from a current sensor. In fact, the data has too much noise. Nevertheless, with a Savitzky-Golay filter I can considerably smooth the curve. Why do you say that it makes far more sense to expect the function to go back down? This is not clear to me.

Comment: I said this because we don't know *what data* this function is based on (you should probably update your post with that information, too). If this is the readout of a current sensor, and current can go up and down, then we know something about what this function will look like: you've cherry-picked an example that hides the fact that it may show multiple peaks and troughs, which means it can have multiple instances of maximum radius of curvature along the curve. If you know that won't happen, please explain why that is in your post, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a continuous curve, nor an approximation of a continuous curve, so we don't have to waste time here: you have a simple polygon. The polygon equivalent to "radius of curvature" is the difference in angle of incidence and angle of refraction: the smaller that difference is, the larger the radius of "curvature" is.

Provided you sample your data properly, we can compute the angular difference at each data point:

```
for (i=1, i<p.length -1):
  vector1 = p[i] - p[i-1] // assuming your language of choice has points as primitives
  vector2 = p[1+1] - p[i] // if not, you'll have to extract x/y separately.
  p[i].angle = findAngle(vector1,vector2)
```

The `findAngle` function should be easy enough to implement, there are a million tutorials on how to implement this in your favourite language (it's basic arithemtic in many, and even built-in for some, languages). And that's it, we've turned our 2D data into 3D data with (x,y,z) coordinates in which `z` represents the local angle in travel across the point.

To then find any "knee", we can look at all sets of three data points (x-1), (x), and (x+1) and consider those `x` where the local angular difference is larger than the angular differences of its neighbours. The `x` with the biggest difference is the "winner": you've found your knee. (or really, *a* knee, since point data makes zero promises not to go up and down many many times, resulting in a polygon with lots of inflections)

```
knee = undefined
max_diff = 0;
for (i=1, i<p.length -1):
  a = p[i].angle

  a1 = p[i-1].angle
  d1 = a1-a

  a3 = p[i+1].angle
  d2 = a3-a

  diff = ... // there's a few ways to compute this
  p[i].diff = diff // always useful if we need to do more work later

  if (diff > max_diff):
    max_diff = diff
    knee = p[i]
```

I've left the diff computation up to you, because maybe you just want d1+d2, or (d1+d2)/2, or maybe you want to switch based on whether d1 or d2 (but not both) are 0, etc.

The important thing to note here, of course, is that we can do all these things "in one go", as we gather data points, since new points don't affect the position of old points, so at some point `n`, we already know the angles up to `n-1` and we already know the knees up to `n-2`, so we can compute all these values in a single linear pass. Nice and efficient.

This approach is analogous to finding the root(s) of the  derivative of a data-fitting curve, but when all we have is numerical data, sometimes the most correct approach is to work with *that data*, not with "a presumed reconstruction of the original thing you derived the data from". In this case, you have *no* idea what your data source is doing between sample points. Maybe it's well behaved, maybe it's not, but *you don't know*, so it's well worth not wasting cycles on complicating the problem and instead work directly with the properties you know are true (and of course, *what they are true for*: these are sensor readings and your sensor can absolutely be noisy or even faulty).

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on Knee/Elbow point detection for some time. By no means, I am an expert. Nevertheless, I tested your example on the code I have implemented so far.

```
Kneedle -> 3.0
L-method -> 4.0
S-method -> 2.0
Menger Curvature -> 1.0
DFDT -> 3.0
DSDT -> 3.0
R-Method -> NA (R2 = NAN)
DK-method -> 1.0
```

K-needle appears to give a good approximation, as DFDT/DSDT and S-method.
As you mentioned kneedle is not relevant to your use case.

DFDT stands for Dynamic First Derivate Threshold.
It computes the first derivative and uses a Thresholding algorithm to detect the knee/elbow point.
DSDT is similar but uses the second derivative, my evaluation shows that they have similar performances.

S-method is an extension of the L-method.
The L-method fits two straight lines to your curve, the interception between the two lines is the knee/elbow point. The best fit is found by looping overall points, fitting the lines and evaluate the MSE (Mean Square Error).
The S-method fits 3 straight lines, this improves the accuracy but also requires some more computation.

All of my code is publicly available on [github](https://github.com/mariolpantunes/ml).
Furthermore, this [article](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/324065529_KneeElbow_estimation_based_on_first_derivative_threshold) can help you found more information about the topic. It is only four pages long so it should be easy to read.
You can use the code, and if you want to discuss any of the methods feel free to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithm:

1) divide range into 3rds. A,B,C

2) For each range (A,B,C) calculate the max slope of any point minus min slope at any point, and call it SlopeDiversity.

3) Whichever third (A,B or C) has the largest slope diversity, take that and repeat the entire process starting with step #1. It's like bisection, but is trisection.

There may also be some bisection algorithm that works, but dividing into 3rds makes sense because you want to throw out the bad parts and keep the best part, which entails breaking into 3 ranges each time.

Another way to 'state that' or do it, is to just pick the 3rd that has the "largest total error" when you diff all the points in it against a simple linear regression model (line formula for THAT 3rd only).

Answer (score 0):

The answer depends on how are you getting these values. The below answer assumes you’re getting a set of these XY numbers on input (like in your example).

And also how you’ve defined the curvature.

For geometric meaning of curvature (that’s independent of axis directions), you can estimate the curvature in point B as `abs( crossproduct(B-A, C-B) ) / length(C-A)`, where A and C are two neighbors points. Because square root (required for length) can be costly esp. on embedded, you can use the square of that value instead.

For algebraic definition of curvature (second derivative, depends a lot on the orientation of axis), see this formula: https://mathformeremortals.wordpress.com/2013/01/12/a-numerical-second-derivative-from-three-points/

**Update:** for geometric meaning of curvature, the above formula is only OK if points are evenly distributed.
For varying points density, better to use [a precise formula](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/133638/467444) for curvature radius. `4*K` = `2*abs( crossproduct(B-A, C-B) )`. Unfortunately you’ll need a single square root (you can first multiply the squares of all 3 sides, then take a single root from the product).

Comment: With the algebraic definition of curvature I get good results for the set of points I provided, but not with smoothed real data. The geometric meaning of curvature seems to work fine even when using real data after filtering. Just to be sure what I'm doing is correct, does `abs(crossproduct(B-A, C-B))` means the norm of the cross product of `(B-A) x (C-B)` ?

Comment: @Marco Cross product of 2D vectors is essentially a scalar: http://allenchou.net/2013/07/cross-product-of-2d-vectors/ So I meant this abs: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/